# Can Ember.Select render a promise for content

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-select

I'm trying to render out a list of items and provide select inputs for each item. The options for select come from the store, so would be a promise when passed to the Ember.Select. Is this possible? It doesn't look like the view will rerender if the content changes, so it seems like I might have to do that.

My template (abbreviated)

```
{{#each fruitBins}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{id}}</td>
      <td> {{view Ember.Select 
                          content=fruitTypes
                          optionLabelPath="content.name"
                          optionValuePath="content.id"
                          prompt="Select a Fruit Type"

                          }}
      </td>
   </tr>
{{/each}}
```

fruit_bins_controller.js:

```
...
fruitTypes: function () {
  return this.store.find('fruitType');
}.property(),
```

The only thing that appears when the select is rendered is the prompt.

Ember: 1.3.1, Data: 1.0.0.beta4

Comment: Is there a proper reason why you have `fruitTypes` as a promised handled in the controller? Why not use the route?

Comment: Are you suggesting to move the `fruitTypes:` function to the route? Just clarifying.

Comment: Yes. moving the `this.store.find('need_type'))` to the `model` hook of the route so Ember waits until that promise fulfils, then you can set up the controller with the value in the `setupController` hook.

Comment: Probably, you can use the `afterModel` hook, if this data is to be loaded apart from the model of this route.

Comment: @Hyder I think @edpaez is correct, looking at the route [`afterModel`](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_afterModel) docs. "[afterModel is] suited to performing logic that can only take place after the model has already resolved". Let me know if that's incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was wrong understanding my issue.

Made the updates as @edpaez suggested, which I think aligns my code with conventions. I added the following to my route:

```
model: function () {
  return Em.RSVP.hash({ 
    content: this.modelFor('<the parent element>'), 
    fruitTypes: this.store.find('fruitType')
  });
},
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  controller.setProperties(model);
}
```

I still had the same problem though and found (forgot) that using the `#each` changes my context.

The solution was to wrap the `#each`:

```
{{#with this as context}}
  {{#each fruitBins}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{id}}</td>
    <td> {{view Ember.Select 
                      content=context.fruitTypes
                      optionLabelPath="content.name"
                      optionValuePath="content.id"
                      prompt="Select a Fruit Type"

                      }}
    </td>
   </tr>
  {{/each}}
{{/with}}
```